# rails button_to with url helper not using index/get

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a button_to and trying to use it with bootstrap3 buttons so the code is as thus:

```
<%= button_to(groups_url, {method: :get} , :class => 'btn btn-default btn-lg') do %> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>Group
<% end %>
```

I have another button here:

```
<%= button_to(providers_url, :class => 'btn btn-default btn-lg') do %> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>Provider
<% end %>
```

Notice the difference the first one works with the {method: :get} if i take that out I get the following error cliking on the button:

`param is missing or the value is empty: group`

In:

```
def group_params
  params.require(:group).permit(:name, :address, :city, :state, :groupzip, :phone, :fax, :npi, :contact, :tin, :startdate, :enddate, :changedate, :change, :notes, :billingid, :mailingaddress, :mailingcity, :mailingstate, :termedcomment, :istermed, :mailingzip)
end
```

I am not sure why its not getting the method get, i mean it is a index route between a post and a get.  Is the do call doing something funky?

Also if I do add the {method: :get} to make clicking on the button NOT give me the error, the button then looks different?! So not sure what to do here to get it to look and work right?

Comment: is it supposed to be a post or a get?

Comment: also, your path looks off to me. what is groups_url?

Comment: groups_path it should be, though can tell no difference.  It is suspposed to just take you to the index of the groups controller.  So thats why it should be a get...   but it is trying to go there as a post and causing that param is missing or the value is empty: group error.

Comment: Maybe. I've never used a path like that before. I always use groups_path. What if you wrap your class in another hash, like - `<%= button_to(groups_url, {method: :get}, {class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg'}) do %> ` Does that keep it from looking different?

Comment: Let me try that, after some thinking also, I think maybe the param missing is cause of the button_to acting like a form, really this could be a link_to I think.  Just didn't know if I could have the same span for the glyph in a link_to

Comment: Hmm, you shouldn't have to say get because it will default to get. What do you have in your controller for index?

Comment: you can do a link_to do with a <button></button> inside the link_to

Comment: `<%= link_to groups_path do %>`
`<button class="btn btn-default btn-lg>Click me</button>`
`<% end %>`